# How to predict a value using pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to use the line of best to predict a value in my datas frame. How would I do this? Is there a function that for example, I can input a year and be given a predicted value for life expectancy?

```
Year    Life Expectancy
1930    59.7
1940    62.9
1950    70.2
1965    67.7
```

How would I calculate a value for the year 1948?

Comment: If you just need a simple linear Ordinary Least Squares regression then you can do that with [`np.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html), and then you can 'predict' the result with [`np.polyval`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html#numpy.polyval)

Comment: That's a very broad question, sir. But I'd say the simplest way to do this is to run an OLS and check the output..

Comment: You could use `interpolate` if you add in a row with year 1948 (and `NaN` Life Expectancy)

Answer (score 3):

As I had a bit of time, for fun a complete example based on @ALollz comment, using `numpy.polyfit()` and `.polyval()`.

```
% matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate some test data with a trend.

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'year': list(range(1900, 2000)),
        'life_exp': np.linspace(50, 80, 100) * ((np.random.randn(100, ) * 0.1) + 1)
    }
)

data[['life_exp']].plot()
```

Giving:

[image]

```
# Fit coefficents.

coef = np.polyfit(data['year'], data['life_exp'], 1)

# Generate predictions for entire series.

data['predicted'] = pd.Series(np.polyval(coef, data['year']))

data[['life_exp', 'predicted']].plot()
```

Which gives us the result we want:

[image]

And we can predict a single year:

```
# Passing in a single year.

x = 1981

print('Predicted life expectancy for {}: {:.2f} years'.format(x, np.polyval(coef, x)))
```

Gives: `Predicted life expectancy for 1981: 72.40 years`

Hopefully this is correct usage, and I learnt something answering this :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
import seaborn as sns    
sns.lmplot(data['Year'],data['Life Expectancy'],data)
```

This would fit a straight line for your given data according to linear regression and you could also figure out any other values such as for year 1948 etc.

For documentation refer :
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html

Comment: I knew `seaborn` was nice for plotting the regression + the confidence interval, but is there anyway to have it actually return the fit that way you can predict without reading it off of the graph?

Comment: You can directly use linear regression using sklearn to fit the values and predict the value you want